# Moving word tables into datagridview in windows c#

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, ms-word

I have an application where the data is stored in word tables. I want to put the contents of the table into gridview. Is it possible to do so. below is a part of the code

```
private void FillDocumentInfo(Word._Document reportDoc, string heading, Hashtable documentInfo)
{
    object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Word.Paragraph oPara;
    object oRng = reportDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
    oPara = reportDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
    oPara.Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
    oPara.Range.Font.Size = 20;
    oPara.Range.Text = heading;
    oPara.Range.Font.Bold = 1;

    oPara.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    Word.Range wrdRng = reportDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
    Word.Table oTable;
    wrdRng = reportDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
    oTable = reportDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, documentInfo.Count, 2, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    oTable.AutoFitBehavior(Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;

    IDictionaryEnumerator _enumerator = documentInfo.GetEnumerator();
    int r = 1, c = 1;
    while (_enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        oTable.Rows[r].Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        oTable.Rows[r].Range.Font.Italic = 1;
        oTable.Cell(r, c++).Range.Text = _enumerator.Key.ToString();
        oTable.Cell(r++, c--).Range.Text = _enumerator.Value.ToString();

        List<string> cellValues = new List<string>();

        string cellContents = _enumerator.Key.ToString();
        string cellcont = _enumerator.Value.ToString();
        // add the cell contents to the array, but remove the strange termination character on the end of the data
        cellValues.Add(cellContents.Remove(cellContents.Length - 1));
        cellValues.Add(cellcont.Remove(cellcont.Length - 1));

        AddWordTableRow(cellValues);
    }                                    
    documentInfo.Clear();
}

public void AddWordTableRow1(string name, string address)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { name, address});
}

public void AddWordTableRow(List<string> cellValues)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; 
    AddWordTableRow1(cellValues[0], cellValues[1]);
}
```

Here am getting cross thread operation exception

Comment: public void AddWordTableRow(List<string> cellValues)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; //error
    AddWordTableRow1(cellValues[0], cellValues[1]);
}

Comment: cross thread operation exceptions are raised when you try and modify a control from a thread from which they were not originally created, ie the GUI thread. You'll need to use InvokeRequired.

Comment: public void AddWordTableRow(List<string> cellValues) { DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow(); //dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = // DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells; Invoke((Action)(() => { AddWordTableRow1(cellValues[0], cellValues[1]); })); } i did these changes and am not getting any error now. thank you

Comment: How do i increase the row and column size of gridview according to the content. only part of text is visible in the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you'll need to invoke on the AddWordTableRow1() method. You can either try this using the Action that you posted in the comment, or you can try using this useful extension method that i have for invoking;

```
public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
```

In your case, use it like so;

```
dataGridView1.InvokeEx(() => dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { name, address}));
```

Edit#1:

Also if you're looking to make the rows / columns pad out to show the data you put in it, try modifying the datagrid properties; **AutoSizeColumnsMode** and **AutoSizeRowsMode**

Comment: I have an other problem here 
       cellValues.Add(cellContents.Remove(cellContents.Length - 1));
        cellValues.Add(cellcont.Remove(cellcont.Length - 1));

        AddWordTableRow(cellValues);

 The last letter in the string is not visible.If i remove -1 and just keep cellcont.Length i am getting startIndex must be less than length of string error. How do i set the length.

Comment: For multiple questions you should open a new question, as opposed to putting them all into one.